# How to move types of file from one user chosen directory to an other?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code that allows me to move and organize four types of files from a folder chosen by the user. Problem: when files are moved instead of ending in the selected folders they end up in a folder first.
Example: A file that should end in

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Jobs\Organization\Screen
```

ends in

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Jobs\Organization
```

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import tkinter as tk
import shutil
import os



def Chiudi():
    window.quit()
    
    
def Avvio_Organizzazione():
    file_path_start = askdirectory()+"/"
    file_path_start = file_path_start.replace("/", "\\\\")
    print(file_path_start)
    
    text_1 = tk.Label(window, text="SELEZIONA CARTELLA\nDI DESTINAZIONE",
                      background="black", fg="white", font=(16))
    text_1.grid(row=4, column=1,
                padx=35, pady=10)
    
    file_path_end = askdirectory()+"/"
    file_path_end = file_path_end.replace("/", "\\\\")
    print(file_path_end)
    
    text_1 = tk.Label(window, text="SELEZIONA CARTELLA\nDI DESTINAZIONE",
                      background="black", fg="black", font=(16))
    text_1.grid(row=4, column=1,
                padx=35, pady=10)
    
    num_file_txt = 1
    path_txt = file_path_end + "KEY"

    num_file_jpg = 1
    path_jpg = file_path_end + "WEB"

    num_file_png = 1
    path_png = file_path_end + "SCREEN"

    num_file_wav = 1
    path_wav = file_path_end + "MIC"
    
    count = 1
    while count <= 9999:
        for filename in os.listdir(file_path_start):
        
            if filename.endswith(".txt"):      
                try:
                    os.rename(file_path_start + filename, "Key_" + str(num_file_txt) + ".txt")
                    if not os.path.exists(path_txt):
                        os.makedirs(path_txt)
                    shutil.move(file_path_start + "Key_" + str(num_file_txt) + ".txt", path_txt)
                    num_file_txt += 1
                except:
                    num_file_txt += 1
        
            elif filename.endswith(".jpg"):
                try:
                    os.rename(file_path_start + filename, "Web_" + str(num_file_jpg) + ".jpg")
                    if not os.path.exists(path_jpg):
                        os.makedirs(path_jpg)
                    shutil.move(file_path_start + "Web_" + str(num_file_jpg) + ".jpg", path_jpg)
                    num_file_jpg += 1
                except:
                    num_file_jpg += 1
        
            elif filename.endswith(".png"):
                try:
                    os.rename(file_path_start + filename, "Screen_" + str(num_file_png) + ".png")
                    if not os.path.exists(path_png):
                        os.makedirs(path_png)
                    shutil.move(file_path_start + "Screen_" + str(num_file_png) + ".png", path_png)
                    num_file_png += 1
                except:
                    num_file_png += 1
        
            elif filename.endswith(".wav"):
                try:
                    os.rename(file_path_start + filename, "Mic_" + str(num_file_wav) + ".wav")
                    if not os.path.exists(path_wav):
                        os.makedirs(path_wav)
                    shutil.move(file_path_start + "Mic_" + str(num_file_wav) + ".wav", path_wav)
                    num_file_wav += 1
                except:
                    num_file_wav += 1
        count += 1
           
    text_2 = tk.Label(window, text="ORGANIZZAZIONE\nTERMINATA!",
                      background="black", fg="white", font=(16))
    text_2.grid(row=4, column=1,
                padx=35, pady=10)
      
    button_close = tk.Button(text="Chiudi", command=Chiudi,
                             height=3, width=25)
    button_close.grid(row=5, column=1,
                      padx=35, pady=10)
    
    
    
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("251x290")
window.title("SHELL 1")
window.resizable(False, False)
window.configure(background="black")

button_1 = tk.Button(text="Organizza File Acquisiti", command=Avvio_Organizzazione,
                     height=3, width=25).grid(row=3, column=1,
                                              padx=35, pady=25)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The target of "os.rename" must contain the file path or it will use current directory. Probably "shutil.move" fails then because of missing source but exception is silently caught.

Comment: However the files are moved from start to end, only instead of ending in `file_path_end \\ KEY` for example, they only end in `file_path_end`.

Comment: How do you run your script? If you run it from command line which is the current working directory when you run it? You can also temporarily place a `raise` in the except-blocks to see a possible exception.

Comment: I run my script from `file_path_end`, The code moves them from `file_path_start` renaming them, KEY 1, KEY 2 etc ... but they end in `file_path_end` instead of `file_path_end\\ KEY`. The files are renamed and moved but placed in the wrong directory.

Comment: As I wrote: "os.rename" uses the current working directory (the one from which you start the script) as target if no full path is specified.

Comment: Perfect I understand you. But I specified the full path with `file_path_start + filename`

Comment: Wait but i have to add the full path in the second argoument too?

Comment: This is the source path. You must also specify target path. "rename" can also move files (with restrictions) and "shutil.move" can also rename (if target is not only an existing directory). You should better use only the latter.

Comment: Okay thanks I understand.  I'm new to Stack Overflow is there a way to thank you?

Comment: This would only be possible for an answer, not a comment, but I won't write one for this. Thanks.

Comment: The best thanks on stack overflow, at least in my opinion, is to write out what answer you figured out and accept it as the answer, so that future people that come to this page with the same problem have an easy solution :).